# Как задать в переменную текущую дату и время при компиляции?

Tags: java, компиляция

В качестве билда программы использую текущую дату и время в специфичном формате на момент компиляции.

```
private final String VERSION_REVISION= "20160216_1708";
```

Как задать переменную что бы при компиляции можно было вставить туда текущую дату и время.

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает такой вариант:
`private final String VERSION_REVISION = new java.util.Date().toString();` Нужно лишь немного подправить.

Comment: @Arsenicum и каждый раз при старте программы будет разная версия. Это явно не то, что требуется.

Comment: Действительно, был невнимателен, извиняюсь. Тогда стоит попробовать через `File().lastModified()`.

Comment: из тех способов, которые я знаю, самый простой и красивый - использовать систему сборки, которая будет в процессе билда собирать java файл по шаблону и включать его в проект.

Comment: @KoVadim а опишите это ответом, какую систему сборки используете и хотя бы ссылку на то как сделать то о чем вы говорите.

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать считывать атрибут Build-Date из манифенста.

Comment: я не использую java уже много лет. Но всегда можно написать make файл, хоть их много кто и не любит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример кода, если использовать File().lastModified():

```
private final String VERSION_REVISION = getClassBuildTime();

private static Date getClassBuildTime() {
    Date d = null;
    Class<?> currentClass = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
    URL resource = currentClass.getResource(currentClass.getSimpleName() + ".class");
    if (resource != null) {
        if (resource.getProtocol().equals("file")) {
            try {
                d = new Date(new File(resource.toURI()).lastModified());
            } catch (URISyntaxException ignored) { }
        } else if (resource.getProtocol().equals("jar")) {
            String path = resource.getPath();
            d = new Date( new File(path.substring(5, path.indexOf("!"))).lastModified());    
        } else if (resource.getProtocol().equals("zip")) {
            String path = resource.getPath();
            File jarFileOnDisk = new File(path.substring(0, path.indexOf("!")));
            try (JarFile jf = new JarFile (jarFileOnDisk)) {
                ZipEntry ze = jf.getEntry (path.substring(path.indexOf("!") + 2));
                long zeTimeLong = ze.getTime ();
                Date zeTimeDate = new Date(zeTimeLong);
                d = zeTimeDate;
            } catch (IOException|RuntimeException ignored) { }
        }
    }
    return d; 
}
```

Как я уже говорил, можете ещё попробовать записать в манифест атрибут Build-Date, а потом считать его:

```
public void readManifest() throws IOException {
    URL res = getClass().getResource(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class");
    JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection) res.openConnection();
    Manifest mf = conn.getManifest();
    Attributes atts = mf.getMainAttributes();

    System.out.println(atts.getValue("Build-Date"));
}
```

[Источник кода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336392/java-print-time-of-last-compilation)

Comment: org.junit Maven не находит зависимость. Манифест надо подкладывать в папку с приложением или он при компиляции внутри jar файла?

Comment: Первый Вариант подошел, второй не смог попробовать зависимость не нашел. Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Я изменил второй вариант. Можете попробовать, но если у вас в манифесте не записывается атрибут Build-Date, то он работать не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Простой пример с использованием Maven. На тот случай, если не строго обязательно зашивать версию в class файле. Версия задается на этапе сборки, и хранится в property внутри JAR.

**Проект**

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───prop
│   │   │           Main.java
│   │   └───resources
│   │           application.properties
```

**application.properties**

```
version = ${version}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <!-- определяем формат версии ПО -->
    <version>${maven.build.timestamp}</version>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <!-- включаем фильтрацию ресурсов -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    // .. 
</build>
```

**Код**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try ( final InputStream stream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties") ) {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(stream);
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("version"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```